# JW Player width can be 160 px?

Tags: iphone, video, safari, jwplayer

I am trying to embed jw player in small space.
So I need to make jw player having 160 px width.

And it looks good in pc browser, but it is broken in iphone safari.
In details, Height is getting larger than expected, and event more than width.
Javascript code looks like the following.

jwplayer("small_player1").setup({
         width: 160,
        height: 90,
         image: "/assets/videos/thumbnails/empty-523x320.png",
         file: "longtail sample video",
         title: ""

So JW-Player can have 160*90 size, and available in iphone?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at?